# Doesn't Alfred worry about Cave Disease?

Tags: dc, batman

Since Alfred is in charge of the housekeeping, and disruption of soil containing bat guano releases infectious elements into the air, has he never expressed any concerns about [Histoplasmosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histoplasmosis), otherwise known as "Cave Disease"?

Comment: Alfred is British. That means he doesn't complain openly, he just grumbles about it later.

Comment: @Valorum as a British man, I approve this

Comment: Actually, some Brits do [more than grumble.](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/uk_news/wales/6235263.stm)

Comment: @gandalf - Suing for compensation is merely an advanced form of grumbling

Comment: Keep calm and spelunk on.

Comment: The Batcave is mainly bottomless pit, so most of the guano ends up naturally dropping down there anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Nice and funny question, let me make an attempt at answering it. First of all, let's consider the hazard. We are not sure if the batcave is located in an endemic area. Some places in the [USA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histoplasmosis) (particularly in states bordering the Ohio River valley and the lower Mississippi River), are known to have it but we're not sure if Gothica is such an area despite bat population.

Let's say they have endemic Histoplasma, one precaution we know they have is the batsuits isolated in [glass cases](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Batcave). That should prevent contamination of the equipment and we can speculate that otherimportant paraphernalia can be protected thusly.
Soils can be [discontaminated](http://www.cdc.gov/niosh/docs/2005-109/pdfs/2005-109.pdf) if done properly by protected workers. Though many equipment for protection exist, a good amount of protection comes from a simple respirator, something that Alfred can (and should) use when cleaning the batcave.

[image: 3M Elastomeric Half-Facepiece Respirator]

Now for the more cannon answer: batman mysteriously took care of it.

[image: probably histoplasma repellent abt-spray]

Comment: so... has he ever expressed concern?

Comment: @ phantom42 Yes, but I was just having fun with a pretty speculative answer, I've linked a more cannon answer. Not that it makes matters more clear.